# Proving nth difference of squares

Tags: proof-explanation

I'm a little stuck on proving $$(b^n-a^n)=(b-a)(a^0b^{n-1}+a^1b^{n-1}+ \cdots + a^{n-1}b^{0}).$$A solution I came across gave this as an answer:
$$(b-a)(b^n + b^{n-1} a+...+ba^{n-1} +a^{n} )\\
=(b-a)b^n + (b-a)b^{n-1} a+...+(b-a)ba^{n-1} +(b-a)a^n\\
=b^n+1 -b^n a+b^n a-b^{n-1} a^2 +...+b^2 a^{n-1} -ba^n +ba^n -a^{n+1}\\
=b^{n+1} -a^{n+1}$$

Since for each $i=0,\ldots,n$, notice that for each term $b^{n-i} a^{i}$ there is a
$-b^{n-i} a^{i}$, so everything cancels except for $b^{n+1} -a^{n+1}$ , so
$$(b-a)(b^n + b^{n-1} a+\cdots +ba^{n-1} +a^n )= b^{n+1} - a^{n+1}$$

But how does proving that $b^{n+1} - a^{n+1}$ is true prove the formula?

Comment: Is your question "This proves the formula for $b^{n+1} - a^{n+1}$, but how do you prove it for $b^n - a^n$?"

Comment: No, my question is how does proving it for n+1 prove it for the n case? I came across the solution online and I was thoroughly confused.

Comment: Do you accept the argument you quote for proving the formula for $b^{n+1}-a^{n+1}$?  It is reasonably convincing, but the dot dot dot in the middle leaves a bit of room for doubt.  If you do, set $n+1=k$ and you have proven it for $a^k-b^k$. If not, you need to formally do the proof using summation signs to make sure you get all the terms.  It will come out OK.

Comment: @RossMillikan I accept the argument and I understand it. I guess I could expand the .. further? If I leave it as n+1, then is the proof still satisfied? Could I let n=n+1 since n is just any arbitrary number?

Comment: n can be any variable.  So you can just relabel it as n+1.  If something is true for *any* n+1 then it is true for n and it is true for n+7.   If you don't like it preceded it with "let m=n-1"  then prove it for "m+1" and point out "m+1=n" so it is proven for "n".  Or Stat the first line with $(b-a)(b^{n-1} + b^{n-2}a + .... + ba^{n-2} + a^{n-1}) = (b^n-a^n) $

Comment: The only reason you might have trouble with $n+1$ instead of $n$ is if it isn't true for $1$ and they are letting $n$ range over $1,2,3,\ldots $.  In this case there is no problem as $b^1-a^1=b-a$ is your base case.  It would have been clearer to prove it for $b^n-a^n$, which works the same way and would avoid your confusion.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! Unfortunately I couldn't find an alternate proof that gives back $b^n - a^n$. I did try proof by induction, but I ended up getting stuck.

Comment: It is odd that the showed it is true for n+1 rather than n.  But if you simply "reset" n to n+1 it is no problem.  There is the assumption that it is true for all $n >= 1$ so it is true for all $n+1$ where $n >= 0$.  But once, you've proven for all $n$ you've prove it for $7$ when $n = 6$ and you've proven it for $8$ when $n=7$.  So if you've proven it for $7$, does it really make any difference if you proved it for $n+1=7$ or $n=7$?  As long as it is true for $7$ does it matter if $7$ is $n $ or $k $ or $n+1$.  It's true for *all* values.  n, or n+1, is just a freakin' variable.

Comment: @fleablood Yes, I understand the concept -- I've already mentioned a few comments up on letting n = n+1 since n itself is arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

If it's true for $n+1$ then it is true for $m=n+1$.  And if is true for $m $ then it is true for $n=m $.

Or, more generally, if you prove it for any arbitrary value, you have proven it for all arbitrary values.  $n$ (for $n \ge 1$) and $n+ 1$ (for $n \ge 0$) or $k +357$ for ($k \ge -356$) are equally arbitrary.

$(b-a)(b^{k+356}+ b^{k+355}a+...+ba^{k+355}+ a^{k+356})=$

$b^{k+357}-a^{357}) $

Is it not clear we have proven it for all variables?

Wha if we were asked to prove $x-y $ divides $x^h - y^h $?  Would we have to prove it all over again just because we proved it for $a,b,n+1$ but not for $y,x,h $?

===

"Unfortunately I had trouble coming up with an alternative proof that gave back $b^n -a^n$"

Seriously???

$(b-a)(a^0b^{n-1} + a^1b^{n-2}+...+a^{n-2}b^1+a^{n-1}b^0)=$

$b ( (a^0b^{n-1} + a^1b^{n-2}+...+a^{n-2}b^1+a^{n-1}b^0) - a (a^0b^{n-1} + a^1b^{n-2}+...+a^{n-2}b^1+a^{n-1}b^0)=$

$b^n +(ab^{n-1}-ab^{n-1}) +....+(a^{n-1}b-a^{n-1}b) - a^n=$

$b^n-a^n $

You weren't able to modify the proof to do it for one lower power?

Answer (score 0):

To prove that 
$$\begin{align}
b^n-a^n &= (b-a)(a^0b^{n-1}+a^1b^{n-1} + \cdots + a^{n-1}b^{0})\\
&=(b-a)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}b^ka^{n-1-k}
\end{align}$$
It suffices to show that $$b^n-1 = (b-1)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}b^k,$$
as follows:
$$\begin{align}
(b-1)\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}b^k &=b\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}b^k-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}b^k\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}b^{k+1}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}b^k\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n}b^{k}-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}b^k\\
&=b^{n}-1\\
\end{align}$$